# error connecting to firebird c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, firebird

I try to connect to Firebird database, but i have

> "Unable to complete network request to host "localhost".
>   -Failed to establish a connection.
>   -Connection refused"

in Firebird log:

> INET/inet_error: connect errno = 111

What does it mean? How to avoid it?

Comment: I highly doubt your *compiler* will print that error message - that's a runtime error. As for the actual problem: Do a search for "socket API connect errno" or similar

Comment: Also, make sure that your Firebird server is actually listening on the ports you expect, on UNIX based systems you can use a command like `netstat`

Answer (score 1):

You either do not have a Firebird server running on localhost, or localhost resolves to the IPv6 address `::1` instead of `127.0.0.1` (Firebird 2.5 and earlier only listens on IPv4 addresses), access is blocked by a firewall, or you specified the wrong port to connect.